# Optimal way to fill std::vector<char> buffer

Tags: c++, stdvector

This buffer should contain slots (three in this example) of equal length ( 20 in this example) 
The buffer has to have contiguous memory so that it can be passed to a C function in non-const fashion.

```
const int slot_size = 20;
std::vector<char> vbuffer;
```

This function takes a string, copies to a temporary buffer of the required size then appeds it to `vbuffer`

```
void prepBuffer( const std::string& s)
{
  std::vector<char> temp(slot_size);
  std::copy(s.c_str(), s.c_str() + s.length() + 1, temp.begin());
  vbuffer.insert(vbuffer.end(), temp.begin(), temp.end());
}
```

Testing the function

```
int main()
{
  vbuffer.reserve(60);
  prepBuffer( "Argentina");
  prepBuffer( "Herzegovina");
  prepBuffer( "Zambia");

  cout << &vbuffer[0] << endl;
  cout << &vbuffer[20] << endl;
  cout << &vbuffer[40] << endl;
}
```

**Question.** There is a lot of string copying in my `prepBuffer` function. I am looking for a better way to fill up `vbuffer` with minimal copying
EDIT
The size of slots is determined elsewhere in the program. But it is not known at compile time.

**EDIT**
In line with my accepted answer below, I have settled on this version

```
void prepBuffer(const std::string& s)
{
  assert(s.size() < slot_size );
  vbuffer.insert(vbuffer.end(), s.begin(), s.end());
  vbuffer.insert(vbuffer.end(), slot_size - s.size(), '\0' ); 
}
```

Suggestions are still welcome

Comment: Do you need the different strings stored end to end? Your code would be a lot simpler if you used `std::vector<std::string>` instead.

Comment: @Praetorian  I had anticipated such a suggestion but forgot to clarify. Just edited my question. Yes the buffer has to have contiguous memory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
vbuffer.reserve(vbuffer.size() + 20);
vbuffer.insert(vbuffer.end(), s.begin(), s.end());
vbuffer.insert(vbuffer.end(), 20 - s.size(), '\0');
```

An additional check on the string length is recommended, along with a policy for handling over-long strings (e.g. `assert(s.size() < 20);`).

Comment: This looks elegant. Any idea how performant this would be compared to James McNellis non-template version.

Comment: I doubt it'd be much worse, and it skips the redundant zero-initializations. Profile and see for yourself, I'd say (and consider readability and maintainability perhaps). If you can hoist the `reserve()` out of the function, all the better.

Comment: I think this is going to result in lots of re-allocations. Potentially too many calls to reserve. Possibly as bad as my version

Comment: Well, if you can predetermine the allocation needs, you can just do a single `reserve()`; or even better, get rid of it entirely and rely on the vector's amortized O(1) insertion. `reserve()` has to be used with care...

Comment: `'\0'` -- the integer value of the character whose integer value is 0 ;-)

Comment: @Kerrek SB I have revisted your answer and now I think it as good as my initial impression led me to believe. But are sure your arguments to `insert` in line 3 are in the correct order? I think it should be `vbuffer.insert(vbuffer.end(), 20 - s.size(), '\0' )` no? Also why is checking size of s important?

Comment: @user841550: You're right, I got the arguments the wrong way round. Fixed! Checking is important so that `20 - s.size()` is indeed a desired value and not an overflow!

Comment: @Kerrek SB. This is it. With one call to `reserve`I think this is the minimum of copying we can get away with. It is how I wanted to implement it but didn't know how to express it as succinctly. I will be changing my accepted answer.

Comment: @user841550:  This is clearly not "the minimum of copying" because it requires that a new `std::string` is constructed and that the contents of the string literal are copied into that `std::string`.  That's one allocation that is unnecessary.

Comment: @James McNellis. I am more concerned about the copying into `vbuffer`. I have control over the argument to prepBuffer function. I could pass a literal string or string object or even a vector<char>. I am certainly still open to suggestions but Kerrek SB
answer seems straight forward and efficient. You second answer might be faster but am not sure about all the potentially many calls to resize; also kind of hard to read.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't use `std::string` at all and avoid the temporary `std::vector`, you can easily do this without any extra dynamic allocation.

```
template <unsigned N>
void prepBuffer(char const (&s)[N])
{
    std::copy(s, s + N, std::back_inserter(vbuffer));
    vbuffer.resize(vbuffer.size() - N + 20);
}
```

Or, since the number of characters to be written is known ahead of time, you could just as easily use a nontemplate function:

```
void prepBuffer(char const* s)
{
    unsigned n = vbuffer.size();
    vbuffer.resize(n + 20);
    while (*s && n != vbuffer.size())
    {
        vbuffer[n] = *s;
        ++n;
        ++s;
    }

    assert(*s == 0 && n != vbuffer.size());
    // Alternatively, throw an exception or handle the error some other way
}
```

Comment: Please can you illustrate usage?

Comment: The usage is no different from your program's usage.

Comment: I would +1 this, but is not **optimal** as requested. No guarantees that vector reallocation -if needed- will be performed only once.

Comment: You better guarantee somehow that this gets inlined, or you'll have plenty of code bloat: one function for every string length!

Comment: @K-ballo:  The OP reserves sufficient space in the container prior to inserting into it.

Comment: @James McNellis: For his current use case, yes, but then a new nation arises and its name takes way more than 60 chars...

Comment: @K-ballo : if such a new nation arises, the OP's program has UB.

Comment: @Kerrek: Code bloat is meaningless. The function is tiny anyway and extra binary size is usually irrelevant.

Comment: @KerrekSB:  Visual C++ will certainly inline the function template.  I can't say what other compilers will do.  That said, because the number of characters added to the container are known in advance (and because that number is decidedly small), it is probably better to use a nontemplate function with a single call to `resize` in advance of the copying; this requires additional writes, but they are likely to have little impact on performance and this allows for fewer calls to `resize` (`back_inserter` is likely to make many calls to `resize` that may not be eliminatable).

Answer (score 1):

Another idea:

```
std::vector<std::array<char, 20> > prepped(3);

strncpy(prepped[0].begin(), "Argentina",   20);
strncpy(prepped[1].begin(), "Herzegovina", 20);
strncpy(prepped[2].begin(), "Zambia",      20);
```

You could write

```
typedef std::vector<std::array<char, 20> > prepped_t;
strncpy(..., ..., sizeof(prepped_t::value_type));
```

in case you wanted to be a bit more flexible when changing the size of the nested array

Comment: A nested array would certainly work and I used it at one time. But it is inflexible. Even though the sizes of slots are known, they are not known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

```
void prepBuffer( const char *s, std::size_t offset)
{
  strncpy(&vbuffer[offset], s, 20);
}
```

Testing the function

```
int main()
{
  vbuffer.resize(60);
  prepBuffer( "Argentina", 0);
  prepBuffer( "Herzegovina", 20);
  prepBuffer( "Zambia", 40);

  cout << &vbuffer[0] << endl;
  cout << &vbuffer[20] << endl;
  cout << &vbuffer[40] << endl;
}
```

That minimizes copying, at the cost of maintainability.

---

Here is nearly-optimal code that is still readable and maintainable.

```
std::string vbuffer;
void prepBuffer( const std::string& s)
{
  vbuffer += s;
  vbuffer.resize( ( (vbuffer.size() +19) / 20) * 20));
}

Testing the function

int main()
{
  vbuffer.reserve(60);
  prepBuffer( "Argentina");
  prepBuffer( "Herzegovina");
  prepBuffer( "Zambia");

  cout << &vbuffer[0] << endl;
  cout << &vbuffer[20] << endl;
  cout << &vbuffer[40] << endl;
}
```